# view as iphone 6 missing in xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I have noticed that "View as iPhone 6" is missing in this area. I am on the latest version of Xcode (8.3.3). Any idea why? Is this perhaps a bug?

[image: missing iPhone 6]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iPhone 7 is there and it has the **same resolution** (750 × 1334) as an iPhone 6. For storyboard previewing, it's all that matters.